# How to display GetResponse form in Fancybox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, fancybox, getresponse

I try to display GetResponse form that I created and get the code from there, to a fancybox popup on wordpress site.

I have a problem displaying it. The content popups but it is empty.

The code from GetResponse looks something like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="there is a code here"></script>`

Here is my html:

`<a href="#open_newsletter_popup" class="click_to_open_np">click</a>
    <div class="newsletter_signup" id="open_newsletter_popup">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="the code is here"></script>
    </div>`

And the jquery to display the fancybox popup window:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery("#open_newsletter_popup").fancybox().trigger('click');
    }, 5000);        
});
```

I hope you have an answer on this.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Scripts inside fancybox may conflict with scripts in your page unless you open them in iframe mode

Comment: I know that, I face that issue, I just can't resolve it...